# Producing an NSDate with NSDateFormatter Yielding nil NSDate Value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to produce a date from a string with the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"ENDINGDATE: %@", [closure objectForKey:@"ENDINGDATE"]);
NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[closure objectForKey:@"ENDINGDATE"]];
```

The ENDINGDATE NSLog produces the following:

```
ENDINGDATE: April, 21 2011 20:00:00
```

Everything seems to be fine, so I am stumped as to why tempDate is being set to nil. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `,` is misplaced. It should be after `MMMM`. So the format should have defined as `MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't find that problem. That indeed fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Please try after removing comma...

You can use following date formates:

d Day of the month as digits; no leading zero for single-digit days.

dd Day of the month as digits; leading zero for single-digit days.

EEE Day of the week as a three-letter abbreviation.

dddd Day of the week as its full name.

m Month as digits; no leading zero for single-digit months.

mm Month as digits; leading zero for single-digit months.

MMM Month as a three-letter abbreviation.

mmmm Month as its full name.

yy Year as last two digits; leading zero for years less than 10.

yyyy Year represented by four digits.

h Hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock).

hh Hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock).

H Hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock).

HH Hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock).

M Minutes; no leading zero for single-digit minutes.

Uppercase M unlike CF timeFormat‘s m to avoid conflict with months.

MM Minutes; leading zero for single-digit minutes.

Uppercase MM unlike CF timeFormat‘s mm to avoid conflict with months.

s Seconds; no leading zero for single-digit seconds.

ss Seconds; leading zero for single-digit seconds.

Comment: I think small m:s are used for minutes, not months.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, if the prototype format doesn't *exactly* match the actual format you get nil.  The misplaced comma is likely your problem (or at least part of it).