# iOS : Date format - Sat | 4.08.2016

Tags: ios, iphone, date, nsdateformatter

I want to display the date in the format "Saturday | 4.08.2016" from the string "2016-01-04 22:00:00 +0000". How can i do this? Is there any in-built method for iOS?

Comment: If I may ask, what does "Sut" represent?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me as a date formatter:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-01-04 22:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate new];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];   
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE | M.dd.yyyy"];
NSString *outputDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", outputDateString);
```

It returns:

```
Output: Mon | 1.04.2016
```

Using "EEEE" returns the full day name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/).
You might use an [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) to store the value.

And you could convert them back and forth. It would be a good practice to do that in a Category of NSDate.

In the .m file:

```
@implementation NSDate (Converter)

// Date format used:
// 2015-09-24T00:00:00+01:00
+ (NSDate *)formatDateFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];

    return date;
}

//  Returns a short formatted string represenation of a date
+ (NSString *)formatStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date {

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM"];

    NSString* formattedString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    return formattedString;
}

@end
```

In the .h file:

```
@interface NSDate (Converter)

+ (NSString *)formatStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date;
+ (NSDate *)formatDateFromString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

This is a nice example what you can do with the formats: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812519/1374488